# Check for queryParams inside component, if not found, navigate

Tags: angular

Overview of what I'm trying to do:

Inside a component, I want to check the URL for a specific queryParam.  If it is found, I want to do one thing.  If not, I want to add a queryParam to the URL and do another thing.

I assumed that the best way to do this would be using ActivatedRoute.snapshot.  However, if I try this:

```
ngOnInit(){
  if (this._route.snapshot.queryParams['id']){
    ...
  } else {
    this._router.navigate([ "home" ], { queryParams: {id:"1"} });
    ...
  }
}
```

Note: _route is an instance of ActivatedRoute and _router is an instance of Router.  Also, I'm in the "home" route here.

Problems:

1. The snapshot is empty no matter what I put in the URL.  I can add a ?id=1 and it will still be an empty object.
2. Since the snapshot is empty, it goes into the else block.  Once there, however, it does not add the queryParam.  No errors, the routing just does not occur.

I notice that I can wrap this if..else inside a setTimeout with 0 ms and it works as I expect it to.  However, I don't want to do this.  Any suggests for the best way to achieve this?

Here's my routing configuration:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: ComponentA,
        children: [
          { path: 'search', component: ComponentB },
          { path: 'rfis', component: ComponentC },
          { path: 'cip', component: ComponentD },
          { path: '', component: ComponentE }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
 })
```

The component that I'm trying to add this logic to is not in the routing.  It is added directly to the HTML template of the home route.  Maybe this is an issue?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Angular 1.x? The tag `angular2` should be used if you're using, well, Angular 2...

Comment: Have you tried `this._route.queryParams.forEach(p => console.log(p['id']);` to check if the parameter gets passed in? Do you have a redirect route that navigates to a different route when you insert the URL with the query parameter?

Comment: I don't have a different route, I don't really want to change routes.  I really just want to add something to the query string if it does not already exist there.  I tried forEach, and if I attempt to add the query param (using navigate) if it is not found, it doesn't update the URL.

Comment: Please post your routes configuration

Comment: I added router config.

Comment: Figured it out.  Seems obvious in retrospect but I can't route from components that aren't routed to.  Thanks all for the assistance.

Comment: @solowt You should add your solution as an answer and accept it, so poor fools like me who stumble upon this will know you've figured it out. I would definitely upvote it.